# When the enrollments were done?

Tags: tense, time

For example,

> Staff members who enroll in courses related to business over the
> summer will have their tuition fees reimbursed in September.

The current problem for me of the above sentence is totally of tense.

As the quoted sentence is ,

> Staff members who enroll**ed** in courses related to business over the
> summer will have their tuition fees reimbursed in September.

I can assume that the staff members enrolled(till in August) courses but in some reasons that the courses have became unable to hold courses , so the staff members will be refunded in September.

But actually the past form symbols doesn't exist with `enroll` in the original sentence, so I am really confusing of it now.

How should I interpret this tense problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some company or business is telling its staff members that if they enroll in courses related to business over the summer, and are required to pay tuition, that their tuition will be refunded in September (after the summer).  There is no reason to assume that this is a refund if the courses aren't completed; the tuition may be refunded if the courses are taken successfully.
(The company or business may even be the university where the courses are offered, if they refund tuition for employees of the university who enroll as students.)

As to the tenses,

> Staff members who **enrolled** ...

would refer to staff members who enrolled prior to the time of the quoted sentence. (I am assuming that is **not** how the sentence was phrased.)

> Staff members who **enroll** ...

refers to staff members who haven't yet enrolled at the time of the sentence, but may be considering enrolling.

They are being told that if they enroll, their fees will be refunded in September.

Comment: Spelling note - Enrol and enroll (verb) are two variants of the same word. Enrol (with one L) is standard in English outside North America. Enroll (with two L's) is standard in American English. The gerund form (enrolling) and participle (enrolled) are the same in both non-American and American English. Also enrollment (American English) and enrolment (outside the U.S.)